# Splitting strings in half, python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this string `my_string = '717460881855742062'` how can I split it in half? The string is auto-generated so just splitting by the `1` won't work

Comment: do you know about slicing and `len(...)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try do this way:

```
firsthalf, secondhalf = my_string[:len(my_string)//2], my_string[len(my_string)//2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

> ```
> my_string = '717460881855742062'
>
> length = int(len(my_string) / 2)
> first_part = my_string[:length]
> second_part = my_string[length:]
>
> print(first_part)
> print(second_part)
> ```

output:

> 717460881
>
> 855742062

You can modify it and make sure you take also handle the situation
where the length%2 is not 0.